# Dynamic row deletion not working properly

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I have an LWC component in which I dynamically add and delete rows. In my parent component, I use a reusable lookup custom LWC component. However, when I delete a specific row in the parent component, the deleted value does not get refreshed for the lookup component. It always deletes the last row, even though in the backend, it correctly deletes the intended value. The issue only occurs in the UI, where the last row is being deleted.

Child Component HTML:

```
<!-- Generic Custom Dropdown with Search LWC -->
<template>
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <!-- Field Label -->
        <label class={labelClass} for="select-sobject-id">{fieldLabel}</label>
        <!--/ Field Label -->
        <div class="slds-form-element_control">
            <!-- Combobox Container -->
            <div class="slds-combobox_container">
                <div class={dropDownClass} aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                    <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">
                        <!-- Readonly Input to display selected value -->
                        <input type="text"
                            class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-combobox__input-value combobox-input-class"
                            id="select-sobject-id" autocomplete="off" data-id="select-sobject-id"
                            aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="listbox-id-11" role="textbox"
                            placeholder={placeholder} title={label} onclick={handleInputClick} value={label} readonly
                            disabled={disabled}></input>
                        <!--/ Readonly Input to display selected value -->

                        <!-- Up Arrow icon div if dropdown open -->
                        <div if:true={isDropdownOpen}>
                            <span
                                class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-up slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right">
                                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:up" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <!--/ Up Arrow icon div if dropdown open -->
                        <!-- Down Arrow icon div if dropdown close -->
                        <div if:false={isDropdownOpen}>
                            <span
                                class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-down slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right">
                                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:down" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <!--/ Down Arrow icon div if dropdown close -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- List box to show dropdown options -->
                    <div id="listbox-id-11" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox">
                        <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                            <li>
                                <!-- Search input box -->
                                <input type="text" class="slds-input search-input-class" role="textbox"
                                    value={inputValue} onkeyup={handleKeyPress} onblur={closeDropdown}></input>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical slds-dropdown_length-5 customClass" tabindex="0"
                            role="presentation">
                            <template for:each={optionsToDisplay} for:item="option">
                                <!-- li to display each option in the list -->
                                <li key={option.value} role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item"
                                    data-label={option.label} data-value={option.value} onclick={optionsClickHandler}
                                    title={option.label}>
                                    <div id={option.value}
                                        class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small"
                                        role="option">
                                        <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span>
                                        <span class="slds-truncate">
                                            <span>{option.label}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <!--/ li to display each option in the list -->
                            </template>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/ List box to show dropdown options -->
                    <div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/ Combobox Container -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<!--/ Generic Custom Dropdown with Search LWC -->
```

Child Component JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

/** The delay used when debouncing event handdlers before invoking functions. */
const delay = 350;
export default class ReusableCustomDropdownWithSearchLwc extends LightningElement {

    //functional properties
    @api fieldLabel;
    @api disabled = false;
    @track openDropDown = false;
    @track inputValue = "";
    @api placeholder = "";
    @api options;
    @track optionsToDisplay;
    @api value = "";
    @track label = "";
    delaytimeout;

    //constructor
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.setOptionsAndValues();
    }

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.openDropDown) {
            this.template.querySelectorAll('.search-input-class').forEach(inputElem => {
                inputElem.focus();
            });
        }
    }

    //Public Method to set options and values
    @api setOptionsAndValues() {
        this.optionsToDisplay = (this.options && this.options.length > 0 ? this.options : []);
        if (this.value && this.value != "") {
            let label = this.getLabel(this.value);
            if (label && label != "") {
                this.label = label;
            }
        }
        else {
            this.label = "";
        }
    }

    //Method to get Label for value provided
    getLabel(value) {
        let selectedObjArray = this.options.filter(obj => obj.value === value);
        if (selectedObjArray && selectedObjArray.length > 0) {
            return selectedObjArray[0].label;
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Method to open listbox dropdown
    openDropDown(event) {
        this.toggleOpenDropDown(true);
    }

    //Method to close listbox dropdown
    closeDropdown(event) {
    
        if (event.relatedTarget && event.relatedTarget.tagName == "UL" && event.relatedTarget.className.includes('customClass')) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(event.relatedTarget.className));
            if (this.openDropDown) {
                this.template.querySelectorAll('.search-input-class').forEach(inputElem => {
                    inputElem.focus();
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            window.setTimeout(() => {
                this.toggleOpenDropDown(false);
            }, 300);
        }
    }

    //Method to handle readonly input click
    handleInputClick(event) {
        this.resetParameters();
        this.toggleOpenDropDown(true);
    }

    //Method to handle key press on text input
    handleKeyPress(event) {
        const searchKey = event.target.value;
        this.setInputValue(searchKey);
        if (this.delaytimeout) {
            window.clearTimeout(this.delaytimeout);
        }

        this.delaytimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            //filter dropdown list based on search key parameter
            this.filterDropdownList(searchKey);
        }, delay);
    }

    //Method to filter dropdown list
    filterDropdownList(key) {
        const filteredOptions = this.options.filter(item => item.label.toLowerCase().includes(key.toLowerCase()));
        this.optionsToDisplay = filteredOptions;
    }

    //Method to handle selected options in listbox
    optionsClickHandler(event) {
        const value = event.target.closest('li').dataset.value;
        const label = event.target.closest('li').dataset.label;
        this.setValues(value, label);
        this.toggleOpenDropDown(false);
        const detail = {};
        detail["value"] = value;
        detail["label"] = label;
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', { detail: detail }));
    }

    //Method to reset necessary properties
    resetParameters() {
        this.setInputValue("");
        this.optionsToDisplay = this.options;
    }

    //Method to set inputValue for search input box
    setInputValue(value) {
        this.inputValue = value;
    }

    //Method to set label and value based on
    //the parameter provided
    setValues(value, label) {
        this.label = label;
        this.value = value;
    }

    //Method to toggle openDropDown state
    toggleOpenDropDown(toggleState) {
        this.openDropDown = toggleState;
    }

    //getter setter for labelClass
    get labelClass() {
        return (this.fieldLabel && this.fieldLabel != "" ? "slds-form-element__label slds-show" : "slds-form-element__label slds-hide")
    }

    //getter setter for dropDownClass
    get dropDownClass() {
        return (this.openDropDown ? "slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open" : "slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click");
    }

    //getter setter for isValueSelected
    get isValueSelected() {
        return (this.label && this.label != "" ? true : false);
    }

    get isDropdownOpen() {
        return (this.openDropDown ? true : false);
    }

}
```

Parent Component HTML:

```
<template>

    <div class="slds-card" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif">

        <!-- Header -->
        <header class="slds-card__header slds-media slds-media_center">
            <div class="slds-media__figure">
                <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:account" size="small"></lightning-icon>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-media__body slds-card__header-title slds-text-title_bold" style="font-size: 14px">
                Add Products
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- Table -->
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-no-row-hover slds-table_cell-buffer" role="grid">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" height="22" style="width: 3rem">Nr.</th>
                <th scope="col" height="22">Products</th>
                <th scope="col" height="22">Quantity</th>
                <th scope="col" height="22" style="width: 3rem"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <template for:each={listOfOppProdcts} for:item="rec">
                <tr key={rec} class="slds-hint-parent">
                    <td style="font-weight: bold">
                        <lightning-formatted-number value={rec.index}></lightning-formatted-number>.
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <template if:true={options}>
                            <c-reusable-custom-dropdown-with-search-lwc options={options} value={rec.Product2Id} label={rec.Product2Name} name={rec.index} onchange={handleOnChange}></c-reusable-custom-dropdown-with-search-lwc>
                        </template>
                      
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <lightning-input type="text" variant="label-hidden" label="" data-id={rec.index} name="Quantity" value={rec.Quantity} onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:delete" alternative-text="Remove" title="Remove" name={rec.index} onclick={removeRow}></lightning-button-icon>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="slds-p-left_small slds-p-vertical_small">
            <lightning-button class="slds-p-right_small" variant="destructive" label="delete all rows" title="delete all rows" icon-name="utility:recycle_bin_full" onclick={removeAllRows}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="add additional row" title="add additional row" icon-name="utility:add" onclick={addNewRow}></lightning-button>
        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer" style="padding: 0.50rem 1rem;">
            <lightning-button icon-name="utility:save" variant="brand" label="Create Accounts" title="Create Accounts" onclick={createAccounts}></lightning-button>
        </footer>
    </div>

</template>
```

Parent Component JS:

```
import {LightningElement, track, wire} from 'lwc';

//APEX-Methods
import insertAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/ReusableCustomDropdownAppController.insertAccounts';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/ReusableCustomDropdownAppController.getAccounts';
import getProductList from '@salesforce/apex/ReusableCustomDropdownAppController.getProductList';
import {ShowToastEvent} from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";

export default class LwcDynamicRecordRowsCreation extends LightningElement {

    @track listOfAccounts;
    @track listOfOppProdcts;

    @track options = [];
    @track value = '';
    @track label = '';
    @track selected = '';

    @track accounts = [];

    @wire(getAccounts)
    wiredAccounts({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.accounts = data;
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching accounts', error);
        }
    }

    @wire(getProductList)
    wiredOptions({ error, data }) {
        console.error('>>> data... ',JSON.stringify(data));
        if (data) {
            this.options = data;
            this.label = data[0].label;
            this.value = data[0].value;
            this.selected = data[0].label;
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching SObject select list', error);
        }
    }
    

    handleOnChange(event) {
        console.log('>>> Inside handleOnChange... ');
        const selectedValue = event.detail.value;
        const selectedLabel = event.detail.label;
        this.selected = selectedLabel;
        console.log('>>> this.selectedValue... '+selectedValue);

        let selectedRowIndex = event.target.name;
        console.log('>>> selectedRowIndex... '+selectedRowIndex);
        this.listOfOppProdcts[selectedRowIndex - 1].Product2Id = selectedValue;
        this.listOfOppProdcts[selectedRowIndex - 1].Product2Name = this.selected;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.initData();
    }

    initData() {
        let listOfOppProdcts = [];
        this.createRow(listOfOppProdcts);
        this.listOfOppProdcts = listOfOppProdcts;
    }

    createRow(listOfOppProdcts) {
        let accountObject = {};
        if(listOfOppProdcts.length > 0) {
            accountObject.index = listOfOppProdcts[listOfOppProdcts.length - 1].index + 1;
        } else {
            accountObject.index = 1;
        }
        accountObject.Product2Id = null;
        accountObject.Product2Name = null;
        accountObject.Quantity = 1;
        listOfOppProdcts.push(accountObject);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new row
     */
    addNewRow() {
        this.createRow(this.listOfOppProdcts);
    }

    /**
     * Removes the selected row
     */
    removeRow(event) {
        let toBeDeletedRowIndex = event.target.name;
        console.log('>>> toBeDeletedRowIndex... '+toBeDeletedRowIndex);
        let listOfOppProdctsTemp = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.listOfOppProdcts.length; i++) {
            let tempRecord = Object.assign({}, this.listOfOppProdcts[i]); //cloning object
            if(tempRecord.index !== toBeDeletedRowIndex) {
                listOfOppProdctsTemp.push(tempRecord);
            }
        }

        console.log('>>> listOfOppProdctsTemp... '+JSON.stringify(listOfOppProdctsTemp));
        for(let i = 0; i < listOfOppProdctsTemp.length; i++) {
            listOfOppProdctsTemp[i].index = i + 1;
        }

        this.listOfOppProdcts = listOfOppProdctsTemp;
    }

    /**
     * Removes all rows
     */
    removeAllRows() {
        let listOfOppProdcts = [];
        this.createRow(listOfOppProdcts);
        this.listOfOppProdcts = listOfOppProdcts;
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        let index = event.target.dataset.id;
        let fieldName = event.target.name;
        let value = event.target.value;

        for(let i = 0; i < this.listOfOppProdcts.length; i++) {
            if(this.listOfOppProdcts[i].index === parseInt(index)) {
                this.listOfOppProdcts[i][fieldName] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    createAccounts() {

        console.log('>>> Inside create accounts... '+JSON.stringify(this.listOfOppProdcts));
        /*
        insertAccounts({
            jsonOfListOfAccounts: JSON.stringify(this.listOfAccounts)
        })
            .then(data => {
                this.initData();
                let event = new ShowToastEvent({
                    message: "Accounts successfully created!",
                    variant: "success",
                    duration: 2000
                });
                this.dispatchEvent(event);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
            */
    }
    
}
```